# Inequality between induced matrix norms implies equality

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces

Let us consider $N_1$ and $N_2$ two induced norms on the space of the square matrices with $n\in\mathbb N^*$ rows and colums.

Assume that $N_1 \leq N_2$.

Is that true that $N_1 = N_2$ ?

[edit] The answer is yes (see Horn and Johnson, Matrix Analysis, 5.6). The proof is based on inequalities with induced norms and the equality is obtained by considering particular rank-one matrices.

Comment: When you say "induced" do you mean they're two operator norms with respect to two norms on an $n$-dimensional vector space?

Comment: Take a norm $\lVert\cdot\rVert_{a}$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$. Define $\lVert\cdot\rVert_{b}\stackrel{\rm def}{=}2\lVert\cdot\rVert_{a}$. Take $N_1,N_2$ to be the corresponding induced norms.

Comment: For me, induced means : N is an induced norm if there exists a norm $\lVert \cdot \rVert$ such that  $\forall M \in \mathscr M_n(\mathbb K), \quad N(M) = \sup_{\lVert x \rVert = 1} \lVert N x\rVert.$

Maybe the correct term is "subordinate norm" ?

Comment: For Clement C., I think that $N_1 = N_2$ in your case.

Comment: @D.J. I must be missing something. Why doesn't the factor 2 carry over?

Comment: @ClementC. E.g., the identity matrix has induced norm $1$, regardless of what vector norm we use.

Comment: Yup, my bad. Thanks. @NormalHuman

Comment: The answer is yes and this is actually well-known. Technically, we say that every induced matrix norm is **minimal**. See section 5.6 of Horn and Johnson's *Matrix Analysis* for proof and discussion.

Comment: I'm gonna read this, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For completeness, I present a proof following section 5.6 of Horn and Johnson's *Matrix Analysis*, which was pointed out by user1551. They prove a stronger result on page 303: if $\|\cdot  \|_\alpha$ and $\|\cdot \|_\beta$ are two induced matrix norms, then the supremum of their ratio is the same regardless of the order:
$$
\sup_{A\ne 0} \frac{\|A  \|_\alpha}{\|A \|_\beta} = \sup_{A\ne 0} \frac{\|A  \|_\beta}{\|A \|_\alpha}
\tag{1}$$
As a special case of (1), if $\|A  \|_\alpha\le \|A \|_\beta$ for all $A$, then also $\|A  \|_\alpha\ge \|A \|_\beta$ for all $A$.

*Proof*: Let $\|\cdot \|_a$ and $\|\cdot \|_b$ be the vector norms inducing  $\|\cdot  \|_\alpha$ and $\|\cdot \|_\beta$. Define 
$$R_{ab} = \sup_{x\ne 0} \frac{\|x\|_a}{\|x\|_b},\qquad
R_{ba} = \sup_{x\ne 0} \frac{\|x\|_b}{\|x\|_a}
$$ 
The claim is that both sides of (1) are equal to $R_{ab}R_{ba}$; clearly it suffices to prove this for one of them. For every $x\ne 0$ we have 
$$
\frac{\|Ax\|_a}{\|x\|_a} \le R_{ab}R_{ba} \frac{\|Ax\|_b}{\|x\|_b} 
$$
hence $\|A\|_\alpha\le R_{ab}R_{ba}\|A\|_\beta$. It remains to construct a matrix $A_0$ for which equality is attained.

Let $y,z$ be two vectors of unit Euclidean norm that attain the suprema $R_{ab}$ and $R_{ba}$, respectively. Let $z_0$ be a normal vector of a supporting hyperplane to the $\|\cdot\|_b$-sphere containing $z$; that is,

- $z_0^*x \le \|x\|_b$ for all $x$, and
- $z_0^*z = \|z\|_b$

where the products are inner products. Let $A_0$ be the outer product of $y$ and $z_0$, denoted $yz_0^*$. This is a rank-one matrix whose range is spanned by $y$ and whose kernel is the complement of $z_0$. By construction, $\|A_0z\|_a = \|yz_0^*z\|_a = \|y\|_a \|z\|_b$, hence $\|A_0\|_\alpha\ge R_{ab}R_{ba}\|y\|_b$.

On the other hand, $\|A_0x\|_b = \|y\|_b |z_0^*x|\le  \|y\|_b\|x\|_b$ for all $x$, which implies $\|A_0\|_\beta\le \|y\|_b$. Thus, 
$$ \|A_0\|_\alpha\ge R_{ab}R_{ba}\|A_0\|_\beta$$
completing the proof.